# C++ Template Function Instantiation Code Size

Tags: c++, templates, optimization, size

I'm trying to reduce the number of template function instantiations, but am running into a snag.

Suppose we have the following class (I know it's not optimized: this is done on purpose to illustrate the issue):

```
//class no_inherit is implemented the same way as class base (below). 
//This is done to illustrate the issue I'm seeing.
template<typename T, size_t SIZE>
class no_inherit
{
private:
    T m_data[SIZE];
    const size_t m_size;

public:
    no_inherit() :m_size(SIZE){}

    T& operator[](size_t i)
    {return m_data[i];}

    inline size_t size() const
    {return m_size;}
};
```

The following function:

```
template<typename T>
void huge_func(T& v)
{
    //..do lots of stuff with v.  For example

    for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        v[i] = v[i] + i;

    //...do lots more with v
}
```

And the following code:

```
int main()
{
    no_inherit<int, 4> v1;
    no_inherit<int, 2> v2;

    huge_func(v1);
    huge_func(v2);
}
```

huge_func() would get instantiated twice:

```
void huge_func(no_inherit<int, 4>& v);
void huge_func(no_inherit<int, 2>& v);
```

Since huge_func() is, well, huge, I'm trying to reduce the instantiation count by taking one of the template parameters and turning it into a dynamic parameter by creating the following class hierarchy:

```
//Base class only has 1 template parameter.
template<typename T>
class base
{
private:
    T *m_data;  
    const size_t m_size; //hold child's templated size parameter.

protected:
    inline base(T* data, size_t size): m_data(data), m_size(size){}

public:
    T& operator[](size_t i)
    {return m_data[i];}

    inline size_t size() const
    {return m_size;}
};

//Child class has two template parameters
template<typename T, size_t SIZE>
class inherit: public base<T>
{
private:    
    T m_data[SIZE];

public:
    //Pass template parameter to base class
    inherit() : base<T>(m_data, SIZE){}
};
```

And I call huge_func() as follows:

```
int main()
{
    inherit<int, 4> v1;
    inherit<int, 2> v2;

    //make sure only one instantiation of huge_func() is made
    //by using the same type.
    base<int> &v1b = v1;
    base<int> &v2b = v2;

    huge_func(v1b); 
    huge_func(v2b);
}
```

This would only instantiate a single huge_func() function:

```
void huge_func(base<int>& v);
```

And thus would decrease the code size.

But ALAS!  The code size increases when I use the class hierarchy.  How is this possible?

Even more bizzare, if I have the following code.

```
int main()
{
    inherit<int, 4> v1;
    inherit<int, 2> v2;

    huge_func(v1);
    huge_func(v2);
}
```

The code size is the same as calling huge_func(v1b) and huge_func(v2b).

What is the compiler doing?

Comment: Have you actually looked at the code generated by the compiler - in other words, have you determined that the first example gives you TWO distinct functions?

Comment: Yes.  In debug builds, the map file has two distinct functions.  Unfortunately, with O3 enabled, the map file doesn't contain any information, and so it's kind of a mystery there, but I can only assume that both version are still present in some way, shape or form.

Comment: Right, so it is probably a case of the compiler inlining the code in O3, so you get more code, but identical code. Try -Os instead if you want smaller code.

Comment: Same code size issue with -OS.  In fact, I've tried all the optimizations (O0, O1, O2, O3, and OS) with the same result (hierarchy generates larger code).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if `huge_func` is indeed "huge", you likely would benefit from splitting it up into several reusable smaller functions.

That aside, you can also template-ize it:

```
template<typename T, int SIZE> void huge_func(no_inherit<T, SIZE>& v)
{
    // function implementation goes here
}
```

Then you are implementing it once, and you maintain your flat class structure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. While this solution would partially solve the problem, it does not work well in the case where huge_func() should accept any type that, for instance, provides the [] operator.  In other words, if huge_func() was to work on arrays as well as classes, I could not force huge_func() to use the no_inherit class.  Also, using the function signature you provided, wouldn't huge_func() still instantiate twice when passing two different no_inherit types to the function?

Comment: To answer your last question, first:  Yes.  Each time you call it with a new set of parameters, you are basically overloading it with a new type.  If having the function compiled twice is your concern, you are only getting around that in the base-derived method by attempting to cast it back to something that has already been instantiated.  You can accomplish the same thing by not making `huge_func` a template (e.g. just make it's parameter a `void*`, or allow it to take in iterators, etc.)  That would create one instance of the function in your compiled code and keep your class structure flat.

Comment: Also, to answer your question about how your code size increases when you use the base-derived method:  there is overhead in using inheritance.  The assembly code it generates has to do a lot of maintenance to maintain vtables.

Comment: Wouldn't calling big_func() with base<int> & be just that: casting the data to a type that has already been instantiated?  Unfortunately, void* won't do in this case (it would be great if I could).  As for iterators, how would they be different from using the base/inherit classes (the only way I could see iterators working is by providing an extra level of indirection by making the [] operator virtual).

Comment: But my classes don't have virtual routines, so there are no vtables to compile.

Comment: I also missed something on my first look:  In your class method, you end up creating 3 classes when you instantiate 2 objects (1 base, and 2 derived) instead of creating just 2.  So you are effectively trading 2 copies of huge_func for 2 copies of inherit while making it harder for the compiler to optimize your code.

Comment: The idea is that the 2 derived classes have extremely small bodies compared to the two large huge_func() bodies, thus resulting in a net gain in code size.  Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: Not necessarily (and apparently not in your situation).  The compiler can optimize templates very well.  It is much more difficult for it to optimize class hierarchies.